# Is there a font that will fill the content area in a button?

Tags: android, android-layout

The following sketch illustrates my problem.
[image]

The top sketch is the standard model for content, padding, and borders.  What I want is shown in the bottom sketch.  I want to make a button that has very little extra space around the letters, which can be all cap.  The best I can do with standard stuff is the middle sketch where the padding is set to 0.  I posted a question on how to get negative padding but it is not defined in Android so that is out.  I can do imagebuttons but there are a set of requirements for my particular problem that make that an issue in that I need to both change the text that is in the button when it is pressed and have the color of the background change when the button has focus.

I have come to realize that the issue is not with setting the parameters in the Android model, the issue is that the content doesn't fill the available space.

My idea is that if there is a set of founts that don't allow for descenders below the baseline of the font or accent marks above the letters, in other words, where the letters fill the content area, or almost fill it, then I am home free.  Apparently I could create custom fonts but if I can avoid trying to find a font editor and learn that I would love to know it.  I have looked and can't find it.  I checked all the Unicode fonts and can't find it. I checked online font selector sites.  I think the issue is that the font I want would make successive lines of text hit or almost hit each other.

If I need to create my own fonts, what font editor should I use?  Maybe there is a way to stretch fonts.  I just want to know how to get fonts that fill the content area with capital letters.

Edited to add this:

Just to clarify.  I need to change the text programmatically. For example, the button says "ON" and when you press it it says "OFF".  I use a bluetooth remote control so need the button background color to change when the button has focus.  These two requirements make using an image problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue on the font is that to fill the area the font needs to go all the way to the top of the accent area and all the way down to the bottom of the decender area.  What I did was found a program called Type 3.2 by CR8Software Solutions.  You load your favorite font and copy one of the scaling actions to get a scale factor of about 1.56, make some adjustments to the baseline and font edges and save it.  The trial version allows you to save up to about capital R so in my case where I just needed a few letters that was fine.  Now I loaded the font into the "assets" folder and added code in the onCreate section of the code like this:

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "startline.ttf");
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSync);
    button.setTypeface(tf);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetTgt);
    button2.setTypeface(tf);
    etc...
```

Now I get all the behavior of a button but the background button is tight against the font.  I like this better than images as I can adjust the size easily and change the text without creating a new image for every thing I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a `view` and set it `background` of your button.In `onDraw()` method of that view(background) you can draw text with any size,margin,... .Also it **may be possible** by changing style of your button.